# Showing URI fragment in Chrome DevTools

Tags: google-chrome, url, google-chrome-devtools

The URL fragment is not shown it seems in the network panel of the Chrome DevTools.

I am trying to debug an issue where after a chain of redirection, the fragment is lost.

Is there a way to have it visible in order to pinpoint the redirection causing the issue ?

Comment: Reproduced. e.g. https://google.com#fragment
devTools doesn't show fragment anywhere on networking tab items, but it's definitely there since there's a redirect to https://www.google.com/#fragment